# Symfony 2 Entity field type with select and/or add new

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

### Context:

Let there be two entities (correctly mapped for Doctrine).

1. `Post` with properties {`$id` (integer, autoinc), `$name` (string), `$tags` (collection of `Tag`)}
2. `Tag`  with properties {`$id` (integer, autoinc), `$name` (string), `$posts` (collection of `Post`)}

Relationship between these two is `Many-To-Many`.

### Problem:

When creating a new `Post`, I want to immediately add tags to it.

If I wanted to add `Tags` that already are peristed, I would create [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), no problem with that.

**But** what would I do, if I wanted to add completely new `Tags` too? (Check some of already existing tags, fill name for new tag, maybe add some another new tag, then after submit assign everyting properly to `Post` entity)

```
    Create new Post:
     Name: [__________]

    Add tags
    |
    |[x] alpha
    |[ ] beta
    |[x] gamma
    |
    |My tag doesnt exist, create new:
    |
    |Name: [__________]
    |
    |+Add another new tag
```

Is there any way to do this? I know the basics of Symfony 2, but have no idea how to deal with this. Also surprised me I havent found my answer anywhere, seems like a common problem to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My Tag entity has a unique field for the tag name. For add Tags I use a new form type and a transformer.

The Form Type:

```
namespace Sg\RecipeBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Sg\RecipeBundle\Form\DataTransformer\TagsDataTransformer;

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var RegistryInterface
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;


    /**
     * Ctor.
     *
     * @param RegistryInterface        $registry        A RegistryInterface instance
     * @param SecurityContextInterface $securityContext A SecurityContextInterface instance
     */
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addViewTransformer(
            new TagsDataTransformer(
                $this->registry,
                $this->securityContext
            ),
            true
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }
}
```

The Transformer:

```
<?php

/*
 * Stepan Tanasiychuk is the author of the original implementation
 * see: https://github.com/stfalcon/BlogBundle/blob/master/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/DataTransformer/EntitiesToStringTransformer.php
 */

namespace Sg\RecipeBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Sg\RecipeBundle\Entity\Tag;

/**
 * Tags DataTransformer.
 */
class TagsDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var SecurityContextInterface
     */
    private $securityContext;


    /**
     * Ctor.
     *
     * @param RegistryInterface        $registry        A RegistryInterface instance
     * @param SecurityContextInterface $securityContext A SecurityContextInterface instance
     */
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, SecurityContextInterface $securityContext)
    {
        $this->em = $registry->getEntityManager();
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    /**
     * Convert string of tags to array.
     *
     * @param string $string
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function stringToArray($string)
    {
        $tags = explode(',', $string);

        // strip whitespaces from beginning and end of a tag text
        foreach ($tags as &$text) {
            $text = trim($text);
        }

        // removes duplicates
        return array_unique($tags);
    }

    /**
     * Transforms tags entities into string (separated by comma).
     *
     * @param Collection | null $tagCollection A collection of entities or NULL
     *
     * @return string | null An string of tags or NULL
     * @throws UnexpectedTypeException
     */
    public function transform($tagCollection)
    {
        if (null === $tagCollection) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!($tagCollection instanceof Collection)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($tagCollection, 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection');
        }

        $tags = array();

        /**
         * @var \Sg\RecipeBundle\Entity\Tag $tag
         */
        foreach ($tagCollection as $tag) {
            array_push($tags, $tag->getName());
        }

        return implode(', ', $tags);
    }

    /**
     * Transforms string into tags entities.
     *
     * @param string | null $data Input string data
     *
     * @return Collection | null
     * @throws UnexpectedTypeException
     * @throws AccessDeniedException
     */
    public function reverseTransform($data)
    {
        if (!$this->securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_AUTHOR')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('Für das Speichern von Tags ist die Autorenrolle notwendig.');
        }

        $tagCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        if ('' === $data || null === $data) {
            return $tagCollection;
        }

        if (!is_string($data)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($data, 'string');
        }

        foreach ($this->stringToArray($data) as $name) {

            $tag = $this->em->getRepository('SgRecipeBundle:Tag')
                ->findOneBy(array('name' => $name));

            if (null === $tag) {
                $tag = new Tag();
                $tag->setName($name);

                $this->em->persist($tag);
            }

            $tagCollection->add($tag);

        }

        return $tagCollection;
    }
}
```

The config.yml

```
recipe.tags.type:
    class: Sg\RecipeBundle\Form\Type\TagType
    arguments: [@doctrine, @security.context]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: tag }
```

use the new Type:

```
        ->add('tags', 'tag', array(
            'label' => 'Tags',
            'required' => false
            ))
```

Similarities, like "symfony" and "smfony" can be prevented with an autocomplete function:

TagController:

```
<?php

namespace Sg\RecipeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * Tag controller.
 *
 * @Route("/tag")
 */
class TagController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get all Tag entities.
     *
     * @Route("/tags", name="tag_tags")
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function getTagsAction()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $isAjax = $request->isXmlHttpRequest();

        if ($isAjax) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $search = $request->query->get('term');

            /**
             * @var \Sg\RecipeBundle\Entity\Repositories\TagRepository $repository
             */
            $repository = $em->getRepository('SgRecipeBundle:Tag');

            $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('t');
            $qb->select('t.name');
            $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->like('t.name', ':search'));
            $qb->setMaxResults(5);
            $qb->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
            $qb->setParameter('search', '%' . $search . '%');

            $results = $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();

            $json = array();
            foreach ($results as $member) {
                $json[] = $member['name'];
            };

            return new Response(json_encode($json));
        }

        return new Response('This is not ajax.', 400);
    }
}
```

form.html.twig:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function split(val) {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }

        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $("#sg_recipebundle_recipetype_tags").autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON( "{{ path('tag_tags') }}", {
                    term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                var term = extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Ok, but this is like _all tags_ are in the same form field - one text field. I would like to eliminate duplicities, this means checkboxes for existing tags, and text fields (one text field for one tag) for new ones. Is that possible? If I understand Transformers correctly, there must more than one for this. And I have absolutely no idea how would the TagType look like then.

Comment: That is correct. Is a single text field. But there are no duplicates are stored!! The Transformer saves only new tags. In your JoinTable then all association be saved. Check out and watch in your database. Checkboxes are not suitable because it sometime too many are. Look at the tags function here at stackoverflow. And If you have to ask, ask ...

Comment: There are no _exact_ duplicities stored. I can see you are filtering them in `stringToArray` in the `Transformer`. But I mean those that are just similar, like "symfony" and "smfony". Thats why I want the checkboxes, so the user can see all available.

Comment: Similarities, like "symfony" and "smfony" can be prevented with an autocomplete function. I have this added in my post. From the use of check boxes I'm still not convinced.

Answer (score 2):

I took a slightly different approach using [Select2's tag input](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags):

[image: Select2 tag input]

It has the advantage that it prevents duplicates on the client side and looks pretty.

To create the newly added entities, I am using a EventSubscriber rather than a DataTransformer.

For a few more details, [see my gist](https://gist.github.com/foaly-nr1/3a58c3d849253812874bb2c2030bd889). Below are the TagType and the AddEntityChoiceSubscriber.

*AppBundle/Form/Type/TagType*:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\EventListener\AddEntityChoiceSubscriber;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $subscriber = new AddEntityChoiceSubscriber($options['em'], $options['class']);
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }
}
```

*AppBundle/Form/EventListener/AddEntityChoiceSubscriber*:

```
<?php

namespace TriprHqBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class AddEntityChoiceSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * The name of the entity
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $entityName;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, string $entityName)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->entityName = $entityName;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit',
        ];
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (!is_array($data) && !($data instanceof \Traversable && $data instanceof \ArrayAccess)) {
            $data = [];
        }

        // loop through all values
        $repository = $this->em->getRepository($this->entityName);
        $choices = array_map('strval', $repository->findAll());
        $className = $repository->getClassName();
        $newChoices = [];
        foreach($data as $key => $choice) {
            // if it's numeric we consider it the primary key of an existing choice
            if(is_numeric($choice) || in_array($choice, $choices)) {
                continue;
            }
            $entity = new $className($choice);
            $newChoices[] = $entity;
            $this->em->persist($entity);
        }
        $this->em->flush();

        // now we need to replace the text values with their new primary key
        // otherwise, the newly added choice won't be marked as selected
        foreach($newChoices as $newChoice) {
            $key = array_search($newChoice->__toString(), $data);
            $data[$key] = $newChoice->getId();
        }

        $event->setData($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many many thanks @Jonny ! You helped me a lot to fnish my own TagType ! :)